# Show queries launched inside trigger postgres

Tags: postgresql, logging, triggers

I'm looking for a way to log queries launched inside trigger procedures. after setting:
log_statement = 'mod'
 in config i can see queries launched by application, but select's inserts and other queries launched inside trigger procedure are not available in log file. is there any way to show those queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html
It creates a special table with all queries, the server executes.

You will need `pg_stat_statements.track ('all')`.

If you need only to track the statements of the trigger consider setting `pg_stat_statements.track ('none')` and then `pg_stat_statements.track ('all')` right before the query that will call trigger. `pg_stat_statements.track ('none')` again after the trigger.